# Requests - post does not returns desired data - ASPX

Tags: python, asp.net, curl, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to get an `html` from one web page which uses `ASP.NET`. When you want to get the `html` using browser, you have to get to menu, set what district and city you want and then click on button. I want to do this automatically but I'm trying to avoid `Selenium` and do that using `requests` module.

This is the page: [Web page](https://cica.vugk.sk/Default.aspx). You have to click on the first square button. Now you are in menu. You can change 3 attributes `okres`, `katastralne uzemie` and `list vlastnictva`. The result depends on this 3 attributes.

(one `okres` contains multiple `katastralne uzemie` which contains multiple `list vlastnictva`)
I've noticed (via Firebug) that before it generates desired `html` it sends `POST` and then `GET`. I've tried to copy `cURL` using `Firebug` and convert it using this web page: [Convert cURL to Python requests](http://curl.trillworks.com/)

```
import requests
cookies = {
    'ASP.NET_SessionId': 'wfq0n5xxu3vbfejq15dblw3b',
}

headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Host': 'cica.vugk.sk',
    'Referer': 'https://cica.vugk.sk/LV_vyber.aspx',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
}

data = 'DropDownList_okres=Martin&DropDownList_ku=Benice&DropDownList_LV=3&Button_LV=Vytvor+LV&__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__LASTFOCUS=&__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwUKMjA5NTU2MjMyNw9kFgICAw9kFgICAw9kFgICAQ9kFgJmD2QWJAIBDw8WAh4EVGV4dAVBVnloxL5hZGFuaWUgbGlzdHUgdmxhc3Ruw61jdHZhIHBvZMS%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%2FFvsWIYXZhC1J1xb5vbWJlcm9rB1NhYmlub3YFU2VuZWMGU2VuaWNhB1NrYWxpY2EFU25pbmEIU29icmFuY2UTU3BpxaFza8OhIE5vdsOhIFZlcxBTdGFyw6EgxL11Ym92xYhhCFN0cm9wa292CFN2aWRuw61rBsWgYcS%2BYQpUb3BvbMSNYW55CVRyZWJpxaFvdglUcmVuxI3DrW4GVHJuYXZhE1R1csSNaWFuc2tlIFRlcGxpY2UKVHZyZG%2FFocOtbg9WZcS%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%2FFvsWIYXZhC1J1xb5vbWJlcm9rB1NhYmlub3YFU2VuZWMGU2VuaWNhB1NrYWxpY2EFU25pbmEIU29icmFuY2UTU3BpxaFza8OhIE5vdsOhIFZlcxBTdGFyw6EgxL11Ym92xYhhCFN0cm9wa292CFN2aWRuw61rBsWgYcS%2BYQpUb3BvbMSNYW55CVRyZWJpxaFvdglUcmVuxI3DrW4GVHJuYXZhE1R1csSNaWFuc2tlIFRlcGxpY2UKVHZyZG%2FFocOtbg9WZcS%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%2FFvUlUTsOBLVJBREnFoEEgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgBR%2FFvUlUTsOBLVJBREnFoEEgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgZxAFBURFVFZBBQVERVRWQWcQBQVERVRWQQUFREVUVkFnEAUIQk9IVU5JQ0UFCEJPSFVOSUNFZxAFE0tPxaBFQ0vDiSBQT0RIUkFESUUFE0tPxaBFQ0vDiSBQT0RIUkFESUVnEAUMQkVMw4EtRFVMSUNFBQxCRUzDgS1EVUxJQ0VnEAUGQkVOSUNFBQZCRU5JQ0VnFgECBmQCJw8PFgQeB1Zpc2libGVoHwFoZGQCLQ8PFgYfAAUJVnl0dm9yIExWHwFoHwJoZGQCLw8PFgYfAAUJVnl0dm9yIExWHwFnHwJnZGQYAQUeX19Db250cm9sc1JlcXVpcmVQb3N0QmFja0tleV9fFgIFEEJ1dHRvbl9VR0tLX2xvZ28FC0J1dHRvbl9Ib21l%2BHQE04rKYRgjB5g9Y45F0MRX4pjk3kUedxTojI0q3D4%3D&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=D2D8B64C&__PREVIOUSPAGE=UxUDG72o3o4p7midSFqrHg5_PEG13fMRp5sNJMwpP-qC3wGpHI4_GTkNvIy7cIfVbN0yXf53hVQQXXhOO-cPd5M9-RzoZkT8Vs3SofvcTUw1&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEdAJgD5oGkuUqe%2BC8nmv4B0SqsgetzUr82VBvG2ZOHv2HiZOp1%2BRXvMvzeKh1mpjXi3wyHzk5XZK4yF0XADSnIsS50oB2sktfd4BtXiPHr7oiKZu7QQRxRxUcmqTKJQ3188B97XkXsVE2%2FZIOanbGK%2BRVSmI%2BHhJhyqN3J0xYepqZL0uiiBcAdrukZZWWGH9G89t47hiE54ChIg1Joe%2F2DXnW7rpxjlb8cWwHl1Mb%2FLqIhjdgOX3QcdgRujyKlQD9rasRWdZutbJBUMPwd1yhOzKbwIZ5ojoOt6kfSLpT%2BFPF3OJlZl83JMx%2BejCkvYtacjwj3%2BXUIX1qKIo5CMU0X9OXACwlfp5j%2FzBAgR%2FsIx7ogHj2R6jdtxGzMM6mpDer7Kt0jyLq1VMLqvGe4%2BmC5umN9SOx0ou76Ate%2Fa%2FD2EAFUkG5%2BBDWf7tdH3pYcFwmzVjmkkDohYjF44eZY67xkVRxwbeWX3ORIOzC3CwgGZ7cUqI4dEiLrTeDuDuj%2FCtQJVAoAw8jFvQr8GAN9uB%2B%2BQPSnp4JXzIVWMt687%2BxORzwYkYlKJhaI0bML6jM0jHlMKrh6UHO1MzWTxAgzhRGzfJ6fboL6wmY6UIAPEjXLg%2B8EpSsp7PparBJecDEIFt3jvzMQZLsJlNEaScOTA%2FgVGCg1XS5zLN6N8K4N%2BOOmbKq8zXP8a5StQVWy71cbj7SuDtP8s56xe3c9StoinYKug2bm0W%2Bz3MWlh8SdR9uvwZzm8a0e%2BKnaLS%2BInnXy4F8ue%2BcHqHrPkbTn4y%2FbKUfmBVEeCZI9UOV2uzpGz%2FyFPgKXGaUaTe7yl4WY4NLHoDCi6ZgsXDLO5tfxQbWwEmY9POR6URzbFKeDn6bJm247n0vH3FTdHUSL7LIUHQFf3ClkMs9wV8T8gYUgGeScbd0ONDUAWzVKW1RhoBzMOE4MuhKRuyRxGkSCQWWSA4bZaiCEMjhp7E5oKN0VazIua06U8FKv%2F65lQNJynqdxPC6Regf59XDoWCR8LJ95Fn0vIXHynFRFS%2FC6rYmR4lS5UOwJ%2BXkss6FXJm7vWD0xbjq1dcjjGxGR8EEMdUFOFJx2CMChoyEkM1vS8n6ZUwm0kv8JmBYnMkBySYIuw2eRcBLuC4U02LcrMZl6lVpzpuYgj2mZJUDDsE0HR9ghgwLfwXOG8bKLlzaaIi6io03JLZkxN2tLSOuwru5%2F7GvyaJenpQ7Vpv44sLXqg7TttcoozGoMfnwbtPUAtTYYQzKBqLxZwQQRgBVYaQiOT1jDEyTEXPgiYONEZkLkOrCKLVmLdLLj7pIvXquAFW3OHsgO1N6mM%2Fya77OiOzKBYpSoSl6f0qDrRBctvfdB%2Fyf47Zp0Yiu4kcNhTBmfMI7QaZv8yhDFy9lQAClYU4nDheSVQySUqFxXem3%2BjVueCLkiRvEvE1%2Fk3qsuOQdEv%2FNkMbUjhFpj0I7gPOd491VRUI%2BZytJ8vXBd%2FLMR8F77tQfn71eRcz1tvfNoX0z%2BTeHfT%2FJYxJtq89ODJT%2BKHQLkiHFT1Cc644qyLYcRFgv8cI3HHTck4Nsgq94v%2FZSb1C%2FmxB4wk9w0vTiA1mPL4f%2FcqPR0HwRDHf9WbSAiujMRx1xfXxpdx5tv4f90au9y6BJ4k4NkSfH4ehfYuInqPyNM1u6HY1H%2F38%2FMi7C46gbGA2L0NJrDdqHz2JarZmsOt9ZIn%2B0CUcmVMk61Ki%2FzfWnXTL9dwq1%2BnDbwcK%2FQwYL9H6F46gTqPbhD0pqmhlr7qIPu2k%2B7oFLyvil7mUlAZgXe32BUdsC26NKUPLpogsVy4l%2B9t%2FiPn5va%2Fse1QPFcyEAQSvCC4uGFnfXvhoN%2FniMJXo8sEi29VrTHN02mJZK80GXMKknteAVvuEKfoIaxC3rkVVHawRdYf1fznCbhuMreZQuLH%2F%2FVvryq08rE7uxikKRUAcqnOjV0i%2Fona10dnMhiCh6pEPt0K3WxTs9w5xh6bMnJH7uCRXc67VMgN2o7trVJsImAsoQqtbt2cJaZRlDSqfEGkrp1s66QZBGICaUZNR64CgnZbp5j%2B6VBl28Hj%2FS%2Fxpuy1FqV%2F6joUdYTHDpKV%2FrjHgRvy5nkzdP%2FFgE8gSF%2FXUhoOvS5Z9%2BO8UTMrzilIG0R%2Bx3DOqv%2BXpyAD47EMkJWVDb1%2B%2BHjNL%2FnD%2BTLd13OcJ7JdBYA2NmfCGxLE0Xc3agdA8q1peXcbXoaM%2BHGVE1TnWpL23JHkgasgSURnWbjlR8WRxOK5AFBIRTJtk7cJIk6w9vgbAYJPSnfB3%2F5e%2Bdknrjqjyet0DkZKbuP%2BDXgmVpNpObrADABRUKJ45TwbgbWLZoBqkrw4FQ1gKUNgqNy12E8ZtDYMZWvU29sHyJiy2oYVKDKFNZxBwFp4da5WmspkW2fKxRtZ185DIwbff%2BVXH7D4OrJvqsJ31BYCflWLrJwnqLo5Eewn0Fy2qec8sj0m0DYH5a6%2BUAqCdB72CLfwCo4ZiUqkIqr7PWzbuTQpTQj8z4%2F0MKMIYMofJ0XGZFHi%2FtZ5MhCLCarxUNoehLxAiLYUnqC%2FwSZh0yoKkR5ZaMGvTQdHH5pyzns8tWfAKrxRYP6dRlOftwL1eRyP5QoNjkCp1yXA4nBZZZQivdgLXvvPvzkl8FemChEvIXpd6zppBMmQU122vQUb1xrz7MsLHuDZN01%2FxY9YCY3CEL0I2L5hbvv0UShZIaQj%2FxZEkJPzUNMiHCtSA%2BJNP7Fl%2F%2FAGZtERE1ucbNKpScH9eCR64vHWljleyc0RLIta5is36bl6FB9pWx41doSorvmyeoHcs%2FNfJzPv6xUmaqz9cuwWndAHsVXFzpyC7cZCwVYt3vdmP57ddR3JGfJbbONYQjpfvMLtmeVs7p2PImZCVM4J%2FLZyWSr5BGEKBFo%2BD%2FHxpcEihdPBHPRAHzhPyu7n6j9k9i%2FMFb2dwRh3D9xzYhatb%2FJZzbjLjHO7hxIVZqnCKbhAq%2Fhj2HF3ihkztXEEKrXG8U5uPcrw3eEbH3YVCCx00XGaUEZZjy%2FKVEOUS4GW5zGAP5gb%2BEIj60gPOs81yoFJJ3iy4mA2SvlYdHNXvrDjrynUL4qbptPU5t%2F8Oyu36El9T0ytSPMCqZ46CYng7YskB17S6HH%2Bh1L7UQrdaijnw7UdfjRYnQJXecugoQ3Ca0Ku8uErrtNZthNdc0WxwLQD75%2BuZODQUpSphk8Y3579IozIVxnA5YcnWv4LGdeDpm8iW8M43NTm6gh4Z2yeSMFPjXpNltyQOyN1tBuRIUanjr4jGkfIaeLIvzJgT84wYT%2F5S1m%2FB6bBLtilvHlh%2BT%2FLHyHB4dHK96S0QWkiVHD3ImgFGu3j%2BrUULAbnMvez2Pd7VSptP%2Fgn4f%2BreEwksG%2BIEGpvkPM5QgKNvBqfii0tYdTHgIrkuIIBYOad0LB6It7adZdNa8c6lDEZleFDJTsL6Tg79825RUMjM42WwA57J2I6qE6FgwyDGWUJgoqXTe4TLtAfmPJ%2FoRAiEOE3R9v1rV5F0g4cvB2zTlCQ2R%2BBXDMN5iQ53827%2BzsBxeKk7o2Uk0BX4v%2B0WJXbVC5fv7S20ItH%2B1DZo9niZE2imcv5GH0WgXwonFgaJ6w2aGoN0phfSuMeANmM4eI0NTxVavqs175%2BY50mgj2Y87oWHNv8W6xuPJ9sM5NRESuw7MUb9KOeuHpmNK4ro33bbiO7VehrQg9x7LnvQtqS1R9azVN3PBvTke8N8rbIDAH%2FS8JyA%2BLuPYEITlWhdNq5t6k7JcK3nu2fHvCFpoPqTGquiOulxMRrLfUnQtXNauJ3pHuFwbex%2B2x7BJtQcurr7QBoIyaFpsru%2Bq2C7L3lqmieHOETVb6Fe8kNuteWqSB0trz09ifArvwTFFH%2F9cyJMYMf93ULxtxmBA7GbbYdpSSknx9C7C77JzDCropMJzjWj6UpAOIllQNxdsw8HTh37%2Bsjnc7RTDuIxNCxFwxbtSv%2FQRxIBhEjXRwOVEGWVVCBbnmeVV%2BKFXCGFVbGw%2FqdzRv%2BgA0YHJ9QoKEFNjbD7ZVboUWuGDbSuT6Dk554SANIJaHoZMxwLFfcdAqe1TT9qO1Cm76%2BkX7pf94POIf8g9MlNpWcJ%2FTE%2FacnAccMm1%2BxlGgGm347LY3Tb03p2Y7XrIF1imdV6YlNcrSwC%2Bp1i6M%2FfJXBg%2BVjKi5mG4Q17jVPY2mFK08DTD48i9%2BTjjePj5AackEVx9AHBVbDu3%2BcMj8Cm0b6m%2FEmGBQ5M8j9SWCR0VoX%2BnNppmZjBwb873CkrkM4Bf7Fy5AwXYSCZ787Yn2CGJSXCMid1%2BpI6eBQ9l2zqXoFr%2BrmYocWGsVFvqVO5zQ17NJO%2FJyLjwvw9lUavVaC9Q%2BAQoJH%2BBw5PvTyvuz4zlTmHKbDkIXn3v9EezqB74iEZvEIHZTyRSGJ2a3vBT3Ls%2FPVh%2B2kqIHsSPIUdqH2VMfOwmlFeore6EGiA4ygGqFCAEVw4LyTG%2BBipVEmggmSJYzQJ4mc2ApoJG%2F3G7I%2BRSlj5SsAdG%2BiYVcHvpe4312SdV1jxaD2D%2BcSUEwUKkxFMFCrAiCcYbk21upW1uDzyikYYBJX5cqYALJCDvwQrLDOKgw1aWDz796bsX5d9kjglHHCna4h8B7n2aozwDaOCLjyX7drMqoJ6f1Wd%2B1Dy%2BiuFhqxP0kleNUEURcDELZo%2FzB3XKdA8qMZ3u5ci%2BEPzQQRrT6qsYz1JjimuUxitKtsv1wr%2FJk8EMX0p3J6bzyBu0srmKPjgf%2Bx7Yhx7mEwRxdtOmdz87Bj3q9zfbyL20uY9TqeIt3903lQlCCCtWcaXOdZTqbXkKXC8Q8gXv38rGZc%2BN0CdVxcc82MupKg0b3TnJZZK9pdRFtuW4rBAkAhw78oxnqnoCW3ohBTRn79h0EMHADZghtuqkDPoTlCby%2Fb5P2Nppq5wPpPeNi%2BnpbzF82s4atQZiT51HDUWpHGw75C2ySevnBbTTElvXQi1yjPoD%2BcLQiSnKs57a%2B1jjmGh3tIcaQ5eHPqhyjXx4g8Tw3Ewd3VIky3nZ79%2BJ9e9bWqlCiuVE7%2BEssdF4FBCsJYv3dBv0hpyZOMaxcgJmfxHczppjetD8spGcLOHuJ5pn6EqPwMpbMtRNG11RQEumElNIv9%2FJOY0i1%2F8MYV%2Fcofwkf2SANtYxdj64l8r1ZRUYvadDRrXk6sJXcxcKL84r2csR5ZEkow%2BaKz2zRamBqgYlH5M5QW%2B3jEHQe3LlJ2IKAl1tRQWpLNuuGVxh0ISAxeE4CrBgT9H%2Bw%2BAL6oE4EcAdCxh%2FE0HP8HZEer5%2FO0Piay75sl%2BLKn1sMj53t6RcPN1rk9RhlhGxox62ao9CrQpe8IptRHxGRrKactah%2FMFbraQTTzmqYZjvQMrxxEjDfCSVl8mszneY8NP8rgZ82HdgzEJ4jztGp4jOJOzV3hH9QIDpS2AhZBHltzRRTJFyrtOZPjiLYymdcYAXVYSsflVNMkzNJgrLGX1L99P%2BT7OxFRVjL8X8P0hJQ8XeYG56NHdp8ndWiSzDx9MT0gN070I5RWbCyK5uaQarQiH5tZ5%2BUNZs4d%2F6WIZUc0%2BQGmjjIsGHXAG6udNrGjwa5jvZs38AoWWF%2BmcTBOXTkbEVXVoyB8hyGH%2BpKoMfHBH%2Fg92RQoscK6yv87cAqcdRUWzA3RRhpopA6RmFdQ1h8ARyZGfH2Yp2C%2F89WqUr2pNaZc%2F75TswLhn8i0TgGGm5DRntwjakKISvoWZ2D5Th%2FeAn7mwTyl%2FN4d6oUKaoUqtQjONiCcrFlLZkTpfLp%2Bl4EnuaWzMOiFSycyYR%2FC%2F7kuQ6jMhis2FDUnnYJBb8RykGWuB7b1LNyYuRW6ee%2FoA0OG8qGojYejBR3V7ZKBVoD6m9U2BWOidZcog%2Fx34boMRBXqTMk5lo%2F5EBmHGIh7DK3Gx0M180wKUv3hScK8n1HKRr6Fxhsidtq2mNqG0rjxa4kxHSF30wIzvbvkqK182b5bMQBF59CkfRuwT92%2B2kfpPLup8AOD6QSqkt%2FVwX8yCqnvqnPorbwyZE2bQYCtEsLjRtrl3rI3E%2FnnwRs53rSXf79APoXY%2BYcl3fFSLG87Ca4S1t797ZhonQDOBXyWUPAL9jD7OiI3myiVU2gDeWLNVmblJMHGB0TznLpGJgjpGDe5RXF7%2BjVTzNQrVR%2FaqmzhsfW8LAjY8oF0dw3Eiaurf7nr5ZqbnOPfyXU6UhAsOIPIMFlZgrM3sEF1LkLk%2FFQ2rVoKRnCiY%2BB1sW2bQpl%2BSAvSvJVC07St2un85Vx1lLAG53J1GKijxdzYAoj0ct8pzJfk%2F5b%2FTtap6Lg1qGZvqKV84aHZPOE9eF4D8g1wnIq9P%2BDMrDP6BgljZ7JEprlYYoFbDZCk19mTitUEl8FH2LSid3493lXrEGDMpurYf6uKXIJSsGpIOW9CjKRpufx1%2BYTlqF3m9roMQiY488j%2F95D%2FoSBCoyMfqLJtLOcH0oWXY1ZnbXFPHEg%2FXtRUnbvg6sf%2F6nyLnLjDkRi1URzzKATdx58VDP1cyggirTddgKvfPNJnQ0daciGOSxQ4WgXUgaJ52IcjXp%2FzP0WckWqBZSTYriQTUGUIVT%2BnS96pZXeTGhK8fduQU7c8M2SM825JH6dZHFUn2xVCdhsr4BhJLf47RKOF009a5o8tDSJ9IInWCAfzUZ6UrD4IuZMEz%2FweI6hEhx3r4Cpam6Y5q%2F%2BQI7IBhggmYz4JlrlJ3lX%2FqqY0ZkXKknOp%2BWz61gF6FDTJZuGYjbyL1Hsbx2gdW9M7yMnocUt5jv0Mo4OfmdwDwD%2FU7%2BUiTC45qxil0P0%2FmiGTAziPukGZ31QzA4fLGT7Ko9kcswIAhI2pxSapI%2FyBIFLMDdZ0SszyjI4SUlERGQmeHYHXFD9ucK7Fr%2BawamPxt4eHzs2fqo4uGbBmelC0vKmQohQ78w4FyZRZOeLuywX8aCaXiyUJB43uzmPzXbrIFlve7OWC9WFAZ1W%2FUovUp%2FenlXVy1ltKy8lAjiQLNVaoBV0XYw%2BLHWl%2FtW%2BTc4hM35cOtbbI2n%2Bu1VupB0v8v%2BDK3Wl5SExl%2BUOpr%2FHvvvOiMYHxOEOpuKmQObqDmTEobMYken%2BbdwvHgYU1SybIdj1rDLKbyYc0FBlfzEFAOaZ9xHfXF5QDxuN%2FVFTjAGuDewJtE4Pxdz7dvJvpBl4DbTB1ZTWM32F0hSugF1oW%2BnGKnn4z0wPDt%2BC2Fs7UbOHKmOByVLGXOwdlvvHUnZdCyyNbyv12qyscKspUr4Fb6hHopTUNdQBXTXbx7H5KtsF29%2BqqfB9rhjY5OsgPxkg%2BJ1F1uzhT0JyxCNZWNeTRMCfWgUvERMHAgN6ofEp%2BehHeZhEF5B5DX1Qlb%2Fa4rg%2BlnglurpMCdXCoDrN8MpknJ62Gp0KInAhx5i7K%2BwJ4YSsnYsjnINXm6N3BCfIXKWuN7YG064ATor%2FIJtREjcQ8mVNSLKW43NjAiT6ZTCOKWn%2F8MPzhFAzga3MfrXYXXjKocVZMaZokcjrYyNjP%2BjKLvZALU41tjOxr6QgoUtUJM0YyAL873%2Bzmzu6Fb3x%2Bp0tV12vMYO%2BuDfdTnep1qd%2FvHYwgdnT9XldW6lnd27cnHEb3o%2F6KXCbW08WlA%2Bw908R2%2F2P7D6Bc8DPLvsPm3XjFsgAQGO59Y0jaCUChS0SPDfGq9NHOfOkbnQG%2FjhOLxJqiLF7pEF9DwRIou7448oPYJ8K0etxVE0iOHlyA0eeiK5ydY4fM18hg9fr6vxXPLVnQQ4zl4zmHKlmXYv%2FbOzNm7B8jVua1V9urIlJmBa8O0CdLh8M1Uh%2BIOn5jJEJskb2IIM8Dl4U4DHYMnH%2FdjE2TiUeSAQofuAJD2v3soOSQowzXkORfv%2F0YAvMa6rUsjaI35g86ygPrbpoy44ozHn%2B2hszTvO8b3RjKQhvgauwo9Yp%2BffgFeFKrRF%2FH1EIHqUBaa9JpYh5wKG0DvT5eqz%2BqMixJNyh9tnarZKNIF6xdBEAx41BRZlTk4LvsMMOfi22oKKJtHdrE3f75%2FojYHaWHZr1bIdemNnnglK5ZsbKDGk9I%2FliYF8wY2k8sr0qHpj5WxFJei2TqClPllHZVWZ6XLqDnavA5jdZL1AHSxBdaL5XBMRuYKG3YR1TAyKQot2v0JT275xSl%2Ft3vEQCL%2BfW9BDEglsMPh1dHnhfuHNWqcDCb5BhZ%2BemTp%2FvrWrr%2BXzPC%2BOxIUqfqEaD4UDt0Az4nQMdFbSdmtiYINwyiEOeDi%2BqH%2FTKn6%2BlTrK7gaLmqyHLxniiAHLDtqOwMvsY7IOp3F%2Be6hmb2%2B%2BDd9dexWGk9NZca8qHOLiX7uZbvYywVhUV6fry3dU3c0Z57ES1l4nloHDLbiqv8FsyuV6a07ly9FK95yC%2F%2BkbtE%2B7IVPntjybX6OuZQiqr2cqGWdA816eqcwaVcQEcUUgj15bxcJuhH%2BpkbQCXnTiEGDuQ%2FJifWPgzM6YCzEOBeaNMDmPr0upVDUxtKC5apmNxmxxjAX37D5dX5tUF6zE08qnBL3oFPSOA%2FhFX%2FVIHEfrU5urq7Sf6uhn1Z7yssLZqNLUmO71Q3inopVwcHlKXEyiWd3E9dbXseo2geo%2B1PlqZRigpqCQfoQrb8X7BdWD0a5ooWSGx%2BgG%2FOX3px2mukjKVpUE76dAhfe%2BTmAflIInDtKkJSimxkxl1qx9Kgut5Qz6mOjG5RSzm%2FwFKct6ohKOgM3Qz9tHtmAXwscaVcqBl0zJe%2B5oydZ%2BrKaWbtcC2%2BsTfzb1QQR6wevBRFJzadIH3IofmGMLyJck%3D'

print requests.post('https://cica.vugk.sk/LV_vyber.aspx', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=data).content
```

This post works correctly. It prints what I'm looking for.

I suppose that it depends (but probably not only on them) on this three things:

```
DropDownList_okres=Martin&DropDownList_ku=Benice&DropDownList_LV=3
```

When I change the `DropDownList_ku` or `DropDownList_LV`, it returns proper result, but if I try to change the first attribute (and add second and third correctly), it says that server didn't recognize request. I can't figure out, how to solve this problem.

Could you help me with that?

Comment: The `data` argument should be a dictionary. No?

Comment: I though the same but it seems that it works this way. At leas if I keep the first argument as is, changing only rest of them. (2)

Answer (score 0):

The `data` should be a dictionary. Try this:

```
data = {
    "DropDownList_okres":"Martin",
    "DropDownList_ku":"Benice",
    "DropDownList_LV":"3"
}
```